# Fazer com que aplicativo verifique atualização de dados a cada X minutos

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, ionic, ionic-popup

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em Cordova e gostaria de que a cada 1 hora por exemplo, a aplicação verificasse se existe alguma alteração nos dados, gostaria que fizesse isto sem que o usuário tenha que abrir o aplicativo, ou seja realmente deixar automático.

Eu encontrei um plugin porem ele só funciona se eu minimizar a aplicação, quero que ele funcione mesmo se a aplicação estiver fechada.

Exemplo: O Whatsapp que mesmo fechado realiza verificação se existe nova mensagem e avisa o usuário.

Alguém conhece alguma solução para este problema?

Comment: @rubStackOverflow esta resposta não me ajuda. atualizei a minha pergunta para ajudar a explicar

Comment: Tem conhecimento de alguma aplicação `Cordova` que tem este comportamento? Penso que esse tipo de ação seja difícil em aplicações não nativas.

Comment: Não conheço nenhuma, em uma conversa me disseram para pesquisar sobre como fazer para um aplicativo iniciar junto com o sistema operacional, me disseram que é este o processo que ocorre com o facebook e whatsapp por exemplo, já ouviu falar nisto?

Comment: Ouvi falar em aplicações nativas não utilizo `Cordova`, veja se isso ajuda: https://github.com/ToniKorin/cordova-plugin-autostart

Comment: Obrigado, mas este plugin não ajuda com o problema :/